# Batch write to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to write data using batch_writer into DynamoDB using Lambda function. I am using "A1" as the partition key for my DynamoDB and when I try to pass the following Json input it works well.

```
{
   "A1":"001",
   "A2":{
          "B1":"100",
          "B2":"200",
          "B3":"300"
        }
}
```

When I try to send the following request I get an error.

```
{
   "A1":{
          "B1":"100",
          "B2":"200",
          "B3":"300"
        }
}
```

Error -

```
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the BatchWriteItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema"
```

Is it possible to write the data into DynamoDB using lambda function for this data and what should I change in my code to do that?

My code -

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    with table.batch_writer() as batch:
        batch.put_item(event)
        return {"code":200, "message":"Data added success"}
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear: "The provided key element does not match the schema". You're trying to store an `event` object, but your table has a different structure. Extract the information from the `event` object, and build a proper record before sending it to DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the table definition, but my bet is that "A1" is the primary key of type string. If you try setting it to a map, it will fail.